# xaml layout: scroll bar disappears during program execution

Tags: wpf, xaml

Ive written a simple xaml layout for a side project I am working on. The scroll bar for my TextBox will show at the beginning when I first launch my application however as soon as I start printing output to the textbox, it will dissappear and I am not sure why. Other answers say that I need to set a static height on my textbox and use VerticalScrollBarVisibility so I have done so but the issue persists. See screenshots below, all help is appreciated.

image 1 of the application when first launched:
[image]
and image 2 of the application when output starts to print:

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="DashboardDeployer.MainWindow"
        x:Name="MainWindowName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:Utility="clr-namespace:DashboardDeployer.Utility" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="Dashboard Deployer"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Height="550" Width="1200" Margin="10" Icon="/DashboardDeployer;component/Blue-Monster.ico">

    <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" MaxWidth="750"
            Margin="10" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="25" />
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          FlowDirection="LeftToRight" MaxWidth="750" >
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="66*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="66*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="29*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="70*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="29" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition x:Name="LastRow" Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="750"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Grid x:Name="BaseDirGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Grid.Row="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">Dex Dashboard base directory</Label>
        <TextBox Height="23" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" 
               Background="{Binding LocationPath, Converter={StaticResource ValidHtmlPathBrushConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"  
               Text="{Binding LocationPath, Mode=TwoWay}" KeyUp="PathTextBox_KeyUp"
               />
        <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="30" Width="100" 
              Command="{Binding BrowseSourceCommand, Mode=OneWay}" >Browse</Button>
        <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" Margin="5" Width="100" 
              Command="{Binding OpenSourceCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding LocationPath, Converter={StaticResource ValidPathBoolConverter}}" >Explorer</Button>
      </Grid>

      <Grid x:Name="OutputDirGrid"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="110*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">Output Directory</Label>
        <TextBox Height="23"  Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" 
               Background="{Binding OutputPath, Converter={StaticResource ValidPathConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"  
               Text="{Binding OutputPath, Mode=TwoWay}" KeyUp="PathTextBox_KeyUp"
               />
        <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="30" Width="100" 
              Command="{Binding BrowseDestCommand, Mode=OneWay}" >Browse</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" Margin="5" Width="100" 
              Command="{Binding OpenDestCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding OutputPath, Converter={StaticResource ValidPathBoolConverter}}" CommandParameter="{Binding OutputPath}">Explorer</Button>
      </Grid>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
      <DockPanel  FlowDirection="LeftToRight">

        <Label>Change the populate document parameter: </Label>
          <CheckBox x:Name="ChangePopulateDocument" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ChangePopulateDocument}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Visibility="{Binding ChangePopulateDocument, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter} }" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
          <Label>Check to add (false), uncheck to remove parameter</Label>
          <CheckBox x:Name="PopulateDocumentRequiresParameter" IsChecked="{Binding Path=PopulateDocumentRequiresParameter}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DockPanel>
      </StackPanel>
      <Button x:Name="Deploy" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="50" Margin="10" Width="150" 
              Command="{Binding PackageAndDeployCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding SourceAndDestAreValid}" >Deploy</Button>
      <Label Grid.Row="4" >Have you gotten latest and compiled in release mode?</Label>
      <ProgressBar x:Name="TheProgressBar" Grid.Row="5" Height="20" Margin="20 5" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsProcessing}"  />
      <TextBox  Name="OutputLog" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Text="{Binding ConsoleText}"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Height="150" />
    </Grid>

  </StackPanel>


</Window>
```

Comment: Unless you cropped the bottom image yourself, the textbox is likely extending beyond the window. Notice how the right side border is missing. Please post your XAML code, then we can probably see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason for the textbox expanding beyond the window size, is because of this line

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="750"/>
```

Generally the layout is needlessly complicated. Would I be wrong if I assume that it has been done by dragging around in the designer? Having columndefinitions as 66* 29* etc. makes it very difficult to control the layout, and judge how it will look runtime.

This is how I would structure it. It was designed in [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/), so I had to remove converters and event handlers.

```
<Page
        x:Name="MainWindowName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:Utility="clr-namespace:DashboardDeployer.Utility" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="Dashboard Deployer"
        Margin="10">

    <Page.Resources>
    </Page.Resources>
  <Grid x:Name="TitlePanel" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="25" />
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" >
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Dex Dashboard base directory</Label>
        <TextBox Height="23" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" 
               Background="Green" Text="{Binding LocationPath, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="30" Width="100" 
              Command="{Binding BrowseSourceCommand, Mode=OneWay}" >Browse</Button>
        <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" Margin="5" Width="100" 
              Command="{Binding OpenSourceCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
              IsEnabled="True" >Explorer</Button>

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">Output Directory</Label>
        <TextBox Height="23" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" 
               Background="Red"  
               Text="{Binding OutputPath, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="30" Width="100"
              Command="{Binding BrowseDestCommand, Mode=OneWay}" >Browse</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" Margin="5" Width="100" 
              Command="{Binding OpenDestCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
              IsEnabled="True">Explorer</Button>
              </Grid>

      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <DockPanel  FlowDirection="LeftToRight">  
            <Label>Change the populate document parameter: </Label>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChangePopulateDocument" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ChangePopulateDocument}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Visibility="Visible" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
            <Label>Check to add (false), uncheck to remove parameter</Label>
            <CheckBox x:Name="PopulateDocumentRequiresParameter" IsChecked="{Binding Path=PopulateDocumentRequiresParameter}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
          </DockPanel>
      </StackPanel>

      <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button x:Name="Deploy" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Margin="10" Width="150" 
              Command="{Binding PackageAndDeployCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding SourceAndDestAreValid}" >Deploy</Button>
      <Label Grid.Row="1" >Have you gotten latest and compiled in release mode?</Label>
      <ProgressBar x:Name="TheProgressBar" Grid.Row="2" Height="20" Margin="20,5" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsProcessing}"  />
      <TextBox  Name="OutputLog" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
                The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
      </TextBox>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```